# How to print with Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Jupyter Notebooks. Taking a python for finance course, and right at the start ran into this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_run():
    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/James/Desktop/MSFT.csv")
    print(df)
```

this runs no errors, but just does not print anything under the cell. I know this must be a silly  thing i'm not doing, but I can't figure it out, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to run the `test_run()` method... Just type `test_run()` at the end of your code or at a new cell

Comment: Thank you, that worked great, adding test_run() solved my problem, now can I ask you why I need to add that , I have not seen that in any book or online help.

Answer (score 2):

If the above code is *exactly* what you're executing, then the code will not output anything.

You are defining a function, but not running that function. The function (when run) will print something to the console (stdout). If run in a jupyter notebook, the output will display in the output cell. However, you are not running the function.

The below should print to the jupyter notebook

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_run():
    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/James/Desktop/MSFT.csv")
    print(df)

test_run()  # run the function
```

Comment: Boy , am I dumb, such a stupid mistake, thank you guys, You are the best!

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Good to get a fresh set of eyes. Good luck!